# WPF/Winform Time Range Selector

Tags: wpf, winforms

I'm looking for a decent WPF or Winform time range selector, much like a home central heating system, where a time range is selectable.

http://lhill.com.au/l%20hill%20web%20page%20pictures/time%20clock%202.jpg

Is there any GUI libraries or examples available to fulfill this need?

Comment: Or even better would be little ticks representing each hour

http://www.alpha-boilers.com/products/images/controls//24_hour_mechanical_clock/24_hour_mechanical_clock.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "radial" gauge controls.

If you search on google you will find lots of controls for Winforms and WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Check out infragistics!!
They have cool range sliders, I have been using infragistics over an year. Their custom support is fine, controls are very cool. Native WPF 4 controls.